# Filling Lua table not going as expected

Tags: lua, lua-table

I am coding a little something in Lua and I've encountered a very frustrating bug/mistake in my code.

```
network = {}
network.neurons = {}

for i=1,4 do
    network.neurons[20000] = {}
    network.neurons[20000][i] = NewNeuron()
    print(network.neurons[20000][i])
end
```

The `NewNeuron()` function creates a new object with some variables. The print() inside this for loop returns the table with the correct variables as expected. The problem comes when I try to use this print again in this loop:

```
for i=1,4 do
    print(network.neurons[20000][i])
end
```

The print then writes 4 console lines as follows:

```
(no return)
(no return)
(no return)
*neuron info that should be printed*
```

It looks as if only the last of the 4 objects exists after I exit the creation loop. Why is this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are resetting the table at the first line inside the loop. Move this line outside the loop.

Comment: Whoa, well seen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning an entirely new table inside the loop when creating a `NewNeuron`. The declaration should be outside:

```
network = {}
network.neurons = {}
network.neurons[20000] = {}

for i=1,4 do
    network.neurons[20000][i] = NewNeuron()
    print(network.neurons[20000][i])
end
```